# AES decryption result varies after openssl upgrade

Tags: c, visual-c++, openssl, aes

My code which was linked to openssl 0.98 had a AES decryption functionality which was working fine.

This is the code.

```
   const int bits = 256;
        AES_KEY key;
        iRes = AES_set_decrypt_key((const unsigned char *)szSecretKey, bits, &key);

        unsigned char szSigBytes[MAX_PATH] = "";
        unsigned char *pSigBytes = szSigBytes;
        unsigned char *pSignature = szSignature;
        AES_decrypt(pSignature, pSigBytes, &key);
        AES_decrypt(pSignature + 16, pSigBytes + 16, &key);

        cout<<pSigBytes<<endl;
```

However, after migrating to openssl 1.0.1p, I had to use the EVP functions as the non EVP functions were failing in FIPS mode. So I modified the code to

```
EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx;    
            int len;


            int plaintext_len;
            int ciphertext_len = strlen((const char*)in);

            if(!(ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new()));


            if(1 != EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_256_ecb(), NULL, SecretKey, NULL))
            return;

          if(1 != EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx, out, &len, in, ciphertext_len))
            return;

          if(1 != EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx, out + 16, &len, in + 16, ciphertext_len - len))
            return; 

          EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(ctx, out + len, &len); 

          EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
```

The results are almost matching, but for some of the few last characters.
Any idea, what am I doing wrong here?

Edit: I see that the second 16 bytes are not getting decrypted while using EVP_DecryptUpdate.

I have extracted the second 16 bytes into an array and tried to decrypt it. I see that it goes successfully when I use AES_decrypt, but returns "" when I use EVP_DecryptUpdate. 
The cipher length is only 2 bytes. Can this be a reason why the decryption is failing?

See the modified code below.

```
    unsigned char temp[MAX_PATH] = "BoQ=\n";
    unsigned char result[MAX_PATH] = "";

    unsigned char data[MAX_PATH] = "";
    Decode(temp, data);


    //Decrypting with AES_Decrypt


   AES_KEY key;

unsigned char DecodedSecretKey[MAX_PATH];
ZeroMemory(DecodedSecretKey, MAX_PATH);
Decode(secretKey, DecodedSecretKey);


AES_set_decrypt_key((const unsigned char *)DecodedSecretKey, 256, &key);

AES_decrypt(data, result, &key);//result returns the proper result
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
//Decrypting with EVP_DecryptUpdate

EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx;    
        int len;


        int plaintext_len;
        int ciphertext_len = strlen((const char*)data);

        if(!(ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new()));


        if(1 != EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_256_ecb(), NULL, SecretKey, NULL))
        return;

      if(1 != EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx, result, &len, data, ciphertext_len))
        return;


      EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(ctx, result + len, &len); 

      EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
//Here the array result is always empty
```

Comment: ECB mode is not recommended, see ECB mode [example image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_Codebook_.28ECB.29).

Comment: So which mode should I be using? With the non EVP version, i.e AES_decrypt, there is no mode specified. So how do I find out which mode should be used for the EVP_Decrypt function?

Comment: In general CBC ode is used, that is sometimes the default. There there is the issue of the iv which should be random bytes generally prepended to the encrypted data. But all these concerns are only necessary if security is needed, just encryption does not produce security.

Comment: You should *not* use `AES_encrypt` and friends. That's a software-only implementation, so you will not enjoy hardware support, like AES-NI. You should be using `EVP_*` functions. See [EVP Symmetric Encryption and Decryption](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption) on the OpenSSL wiki. In fact, you should probably be using authenticated encryption because it provides *both* confidentiality and authenticity. See [EVP Authenticated Encryption and Decryption](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Authenticated_Encryption_and_Decryption) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out the problem. It was really a very silly one.

```
int ciphertext_len = strlen((const char*)data);
```

I was deciding the length of an encrypted string, using strlen, which is wrong, and I just learned it the hard way.

Answer (score 1):

Usage of `EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx, out, &len, in, ciphertext_len)` is wrong.

Here, `len` must be initialized to the number of bytes in `out` array. As per my knowledge, if you call once with `len` as full length and `cipthertext_len`, it must decrypt all the encrypted text. Second call is not required. Either:

```
len = <full length of buffer>;
EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx, out, &len, in, ciphertext_len);
```

or

```
len = 16;
EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx, out, &len, in, len);
len = 16;
EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx, out+16, &len, in+16, len);
```

I prefer first approach. If you require special padding, then you can use additional call to handle last block.

Comment: It didnt work. The second 16 bytes of data when decrypted with EVP_DecryptUpdate always return an empty string. I think that is the problem. I have modified the question to specify this. Please have a look